# About the usage of exec for Python in Java?

Tags: java, python, process

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String.format("python.exe test.py %s %d", "lightStatus", 1));
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String deviceCmd = reader.readLine();
System.out.println(deviceCmd);
```

test.py:

```
import sys
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    para = sys.argv[1]
    value = sys.argv[2]
    message = '{"message": "change_lightStatus", "value": %d}'%int(value)
    print (message)
```

**Wht the Java output is null? I want to get the String**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no error in your program. It might be printing null due to some exception. Are you capturing the exceptions or at least printing them? Possible causes may be

1. Python interpreter not found (due to incorrect system PATH for
   example),
2. File test.py not found (check if the file is in the same
   directory from where you are running the Java Virtual Machine)
3. Other platform related cause.

Check for exceptions. They might give you some valuable information.

Comment: Thank you very very much! I dismiss a mistake on the related codes.

Comment: @user3327884: can you clarify the problem you had?